# RPi Zero as a USB sniffer: how is it practically possible?

Tags: usb

It is known, that USB technology provides data dissemination over all downstream USB ports connected to some USB host. Thus every perepheral device connected to USB port (enabled by host) could potentially reads host OUT transactions.
RPi Zero could work in device (slave) mode, so it could be theoretically possible to enable USB sniffing feature. From the box RPi Zero allows to monitor USB transactions on it's own USB bus if RPi Zero is configured as USB Host Controller (master).
How is it possible (if it is) to capture USB OUT transactions of other USB Host Controller to which RPi Zero is connected as a slave?